# Can I nest similar model relationships under a custom type in Graphene Django?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

Assuming I have a Django model with a number of relationships that are related, is it possible to nest them through a non-model type for querying purposes? A specific example:

Assume I have a model `Organization` with relationships that include `X_projects`, `X_accounts`,  etc which are also Django models.

It is pretty easy to allow queries like:

```
query fetchOrganization($id: Int!) {
  organization(id: $id) {
    id,
    ... other fields ...
    X_accounts {
      ...
    }
    X_projects {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

but I would prefer to support queries like:

```
query fetchOrganization($id: Int!) {
  organization(id: $id) {
    id,
    ... other fields ...
    X {
      accounts {
        ...
      }
      projects {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given that `X` doesn't actually make sense to be a Django model / relation on the backend, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#plain-objecttypes ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by modifying a new resolver for "X" that uses a custom object type that has fields for accounts and projects.

You'll need to create a new composite object type that is a container for accounts and projects, for example (assuming that you've also defined a `DjangoObjectType` class already for your account and project models)

```
class XType(graphene.ObjectType):
    account = graphene.Field(AccountType)
    project = graphene.Field(ProjectType)
```

Then modify your Organization type definition to add the new field, something like

```
class OrganizationType(DjangoObjectType):
   x = graphene.Field(XType)

   class Meta:
        model = Organization
        # You might want to exclude the x_project and x_account fields

   def resolve_x(self, info, **kwargs):
       # You'll have to work out how to parse arguments and fetch account and project
       return XType(account=account, project=project)
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!